# Physical explanation of the non-analyticities in the ising model in the vicinity of zero external field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ising-model, ferromagnetism

In the Ising model when $T<T_C$ with $T_C$ being the Curie temperature, there is a finite jump of the mean magnetization per spin, $m$, as the external field crosses $0$ (goes from negative values to positive or vice versa). What is the physical explanation of this non-analyticity?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of answer you are expecting. Don't you think that the Peierls argument provides a very clear picture explaining the existence of this phase transition (at least at very low temperatures)? Alternatively (although closely related), you can understand the onset of long-range order as a percolation phenomenon (through the so-called Fortuin-Kasteleyn representation of the model as a dependent percolation model). Both these point of view provide a clear explanation of the mechanism at play...

Comment: Although the fact that you chose as first tag "eletromagnetism" might indicate that you are after something quite different (the phase transition has basically nothing to do with electromagnetism)...